# What GetItemsOfType() sitecore extension function return?

Tags: sitecore, xslt-1.0

As I'm concerned with performance issues relating to ***IsItemOfType()*** function ([read more here](http://briancaos.wordpress.com/2008/11/05/poor-performance-with-scisitemoftype/)), I'm trying to rewrite it using ***GetItemsOfType()*** function.

Here is a code:

```
<xsl:variable name="home" select="ancestor-or-self::item[sc:IsItemOfType('_MenuRoot',.)]"></xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="home2" select="sc:GetItemsOfType('_MenuRoot', ./ancestor-or-self::item)"></xsl:variable>        
<div>
   <xsl:value-of select="count($home/item)" /> <!-- returns 4 -->
   <br />
      <xsl:value-of select="count($home2/item)" /> <!-- returns 0 ??? --> 
   <br />
</div>
```

Unfortunately ***GetItemsOfType()*** function is not returning item with children?
Any idea why?

Comment: Does you menu root change? If it's constant I would hard code it.

Comment: @marto, thanks for response, but I don't like suggested approach since I'm creating dependency and loosing re-usability (if I understand your suggestion right (referencing menu root item by key/id/name))

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the GetItemsOfType() only looks on templates inherited from the current template of the item. So if item1 is of template t1, and t1 inherits from t2, it will only return the item1, if you ask if it inherits from t2 and not t1.

You could just code it your self. It is not that hard. You can do something like this:

```
    public bool InheritsFrom(Item item, ID templateIdToTest)
    {
      Template template = TemplateManager.GetTemplate(item);

      if (template.ID == templateIdToTest)
        return true;

      return template.DescendsFrom(templateIdToTest);
    }
```